# Parsing a file, and storing it into a BST

Tags: c, string, parsing, binary-tree, strtok

First off I know this program is kind of lengthy, but if I don't post all of it you would probably get confused. Basically I need to read in a file of about 5 lines of text, parse each line using the strtok function, then store the strings that I get into a binary tree. Then the user will search the binary tree to see if the command he searched is located in the tree. Right now I have one type of compile error that I can not figure out for the life of me. So I havent even started compiling yet, and once I start compiling im sure there will be more errors. Like I said I know its fairly long, so any help is appreciated. I will post my code then the sample output that was given and then the compile error I can not figure out. Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define COMMAND_NAME_LEN 50
#define MAX_SPLIT_SIZE 50
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 50

typedef struct Command_ {
    char name[COMMAND_NAME_LEN];
    int expected_param_count;
    struct Command_ *left;
    struct Command_ *right;
}Command;


typedef struct StringArray_ {
    char **strings;
    int size;
}StringArray;

StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters);
void free_string_array(StringArray *sr);
void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file);
void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data);
Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command);
Command* create_command(char **data);
void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node);
void display_commands(Command *node);


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
            printf("%s is missing commands.dat\n", argv[0]);
            return 0;
    }


    Command* options = NULL;
    create_commands_tree(&options,argv[1]);
    int checking = 1;

    char input_buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];

    do {
            printf("Command: ");
            fgets(input_buffer,MAX_BUFF_SIZE,stdin);
            StringArray* parsed_input = tokenizer(input_buffer," \n");
            Command* c = get_command(options,parsed_input->strings[0]);

            if( c && parsed_input->size == c->expected_param_count) {
                    if (strcmp(c->name, "quit") == 0){
                                    checking = 0;
                    }
                    printf("Valid command used\n");
            }
            else {
                    printf("Invalid command, please try again\n");
            }
            free_string_array(parsed_input);

    }while (checking);

    destroy_commands_tree(options);

}


void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file) {

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(file, "r");
    char strings[256];
    Command *temp;
    StringArray *temp2;

    while(fgets(strings,100,input) != NULL){

            temp2 = tokenizer(strings, "\n");
            insert_into_commands_tree(&temp,temp2->strings);
    }
}

void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data) {

    Command **new_ = node;

    if(node == NULL){
            *new_ = create_command(data);
    }
    else if( new_ != NULL){
            if(strcmp(data[0],(*new_)->name) < 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*new_)->left,data);
            else if(strcmp(data[0], (*new_)->name) > 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*new_)->right,data);
    }


}

Command* create_command(char **data) {

    Command* new_;
    new_ = (Command*)malloc(sizeof(Command));
    strncpy(new_->name, data[0], COMMAND_NAME_LEN);
    new_->expected_param_count = 0;
    new_->right = NULL;
    new_->left = NULL;


    return new_;

}

Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command) {

    Command *temp = node;
    int compare;

    if(temp){
            compare = strcmp(node->name, command);
            if(compare == 0){
                    return temp;
            }
            else if(compare < 0){
                    return (get_command(node->right, command));
            }
            else{
                    if(compare > 0){
                            return (get_command(node->left, command));
            }}

    }
   return temp;
}

void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node) {

    if( node == NULL){
            return;
            }

    destroy_commands_tree(node->left);
    destroy_commands_tree(node->right);
    free(node);

}
void display_commands(Command *node) {

      if(node != NULL){
            printf("\npickup <item>");
            printf("\nhelp ");
            printf("\nquit ");
            printf("\nload <file>\n\n");
}
}
 StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters){

    StringArray *temp = (StringArray*)malloc(sizeof(StringArray));;
    char *split;

    split = strtok(string, delimiters);

    while(split != NULL)
    {
            split = strtok(string, delimiters);
            temp->strings = &split;
    }
    return temp;
}

void free_string_array(StringArray *sr) {

    while(sr != NULL)
            free(sr);

    free(sr);

}
```

Here is the sample output that was given:

```
]$ ./a.out commands.dat 
Command: pickup 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: pickup ball 
Valid command used 
Command: quit 1 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load bak.sav 
Valid command used 
Command: help
Valid command used
Command: help 2 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: quit 
Valid command used
```

And the file that we read in is as follows:

```
pickup,2
help,1
quit,1
load,2
```

Comment: `new_` is not a `Command` struct, but is instead a double pointer to a `Command` struct. To access a member, you need to do `(*new_)->name`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my insert function, but I am still getting a compile error having to do with a difference in types. I updated the original post

Comment: @johnnyDepp please update your code, the one in your question reflects only the old errors

Comment: Your `create_commands_tree()` function doesn't use its first argument, which is going to be a problem.  It's a pity that your compilation problems are related to the type of the unused argument.  Then, when you call it, you're passing the wrong type to it. To satisfy the compiler, you replace `insert_into_commands_tree((*new_)->left,data);` with `insert_into_commands_tree(&(*new_)->left, data);`.  Similarly with line 96.  `display_commands()` doesn't use its `node` parameter; `get_command()` needs to return a value.

Comment: I did update my code. I updated my insert_into_commands_tree function and updated the errors. Did you need something else updated?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot!! I will update my new code now. I am no longer getting compile errors

Comment: I am getting a seg fault now, When I compile with gdb I believe it tells me its around where my fgets statement is

Comment: DO NOT TRY TO ERASE YOUR QUESTION!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Command **new_ = node;
```

here the variable `new_` is a pointer to a pointer, and you try to use ist like this

```
new_->name
```

to access the name member of your struct.

You need to derefence it to have a `Command*` on which you can use the `->` operator, so doing:

```
(*new_)->name;
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense, but I am still getting different compile errors now. I updated my post with what I changed and the new errors

Comment: `insert_into_commands_tree` needs to return a value if you plan to assign it to something.

Comment: I thought since the prototype started off with void you couldnt return anything to it?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your fix isn't complete, there's still a compile error after applying it because of the `(*new_)->left = insert_into_commands_tree((*new_)->left, data);` assignment.

Comment: My answer addressed only the error `request for member ‘...’ in something not a structure or union`, as per first version of the question. It was not my intention to fix the hole code.

Comment: ha, cause theres an extreme amount of things wrong with it I know!! I appreciate the help @A4L